# Difference in the eigenvalues of random matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, random

I am a novice in  Mathematica and coding, in general. I have doubts in understanding a  code in which nearest neighboring distance between eigen values of random matrices is evaluated.

```
    (* No. of members in ensemble=ns; Matrix dimension=n*)
    ns = 1000;
    n = 20
    Ev = {}; Sp = {}; Xd = {}; Sxd = {};
    Monitor[For[i = 1, i < ns + 1, i++, {
    A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}];
    H = (A + Transpose[A])/Sqrt[2 n];
   \[CapitalLambda] = Sort[Eigenvalues[H]];
    S = Table[\[CapitalLambda][[j + 1]] - \[CapitalLambda][[j]], {j, 1,
    n - 1}];
    Ev = Join[Ev, \[CapitalLambda]];
    Sp = Join[Sp, S];

     X = Table[
     n/(2 \[Pi])
     NIntegrate[Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, -2,  \[CapitalLambda][[j]]}], {j, 
     1, n}];
     Sx = Table[X[[j + 1]] - X[[j]], {j, 1, n - 1}];
     Xd = Join[Xd, X];
     Sxd = Join[Sxd, Sx];
     }
     ], i]
```

1. Can the following be explained?
    Ev = Join[Ev, Λ];
    Sp = Join[Sp, S]; 
   I know Join is meant to concatenate two lists but here the variable on lhs Ev is also on the rhs in the argument of Join. So What does these two assignments mean and what purpose do they serve here?
2. If I need to plot only a hisrogram of Eigen values Ev, Would Sorting the list of eigen values make any difference? I mean one can still have the histogram without having to sort them. Isn't it?
3. I wanted to do this whole task by functional programming. If anyone can give hint on how to start and proceed for that.

Thank you.

Comment: The fact that `Ev` is on the rhs is totally fine. The current value of `Ev` just gets copied in, joined to `\[CapitalLambda]` and that gets assigned to `Ev`. I don't have the time right now to write you a functional implementation, but a quick glance at your code suggests you'll want to use want `Fold`. Also sorting the eigenvalues won't matter at all. `Histogram` will do that automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured out why Ev is on rhs after posting the question.Thanks for help.